# How to achieve connection pooling for Apache camel cxf?

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-camel-3

first of all, I am very new to the Apache camel,
I am using 2.18.0 version for Apache camel.
Below are the dependencies I have in my project:

1. camel-core
2. camel-mina2
3. camel-spring
4. camel-stream
5. camel-script
6. camel-cxf
7. camel-jetty9
8. cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty

The routes are defined in xml files and I am using `ProducerTemplate` to asynchronously sends the message

`ex: producerTempInstance.asyncSendBody(.....);`

Now from logs what I can see is the connection getting established for every request, which I dont need, so I thought of maintaining a connection pool for CXF.

But I am unaware of how to achieve it ?

From this documentation https://cxf.apache.org/docs/asynchronous-client-http-transport.html, it says

> By default, CXF uses a transport based on the in-JDK HttpURLConnection object to perform HTTP requests.

does that mean if I just add properties like `http.maxConnection or keepAlive` for my JVM that will do the trick?

But again I am async operations, so will it work in this case as well ?

Also I do see the properties,

> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.async.CONNECTION_TTL,
> org.apache.cxf.transport.http.async.SO_KEEPALIVE

but where do I add them ? and is there any Java way to achieve the same ?

Please let me know if any further info is needed, even if you could nudge me in right direction that will help, Thanks :)